# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'X'.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript

ошибка на строке `const c: IDefSettings = {};`

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IDefSettings'.ts(2322)

если заменить на `const c = {};`, то на `c[key]` появляется

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)

и на `return c;`

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IDefSettings'.ts(2322)

```
interface IModelSettings {
  min: number;
  max: number;
  from: number;
  to: number;
  step: number;
  stepInPrecents: number;
  currentPos: number;
  curPosInPoints: number | undefined;
  posWithStepInPercents: number;

  [index: string]: string | number | undefined;
}

interface IViewSettings {
  range: boolean;
  scale: boolean;
  tooltips: boolean;
  vertical: boolean;
  confpanel: boolean;
  bar: boolean;

  thumbMarginFrom: number;
  thumbMarginTo: number;
  rangeMarginFrom: number;
  rangeMarginTo: number;

  [index: string]: string | boolean | number;
}

interface IUserSettings {
  min ? : number;
  max ? : number;
  from ? : number;
  to ? : number;
  step ? : number;
  range ? : boolean;
  scale ? : boolean;
  vertical ? : boolean;
  tooltips ? : boolean;
  confpanel ? : boolean;
  bar ? : boolean;
}

type IDefSettings = IViewSettings | IModelSettings;

function updateObjectValues(
  defaultSettings: IDefSettings,
  userSettings: IUserSettings,
): IDefSettings {
  // error
  const c: IDefSettings = {};

  const keys: string[] = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(defaultSettings);

  keys.forEach((key) => {
    c[key] = key in userSettings ?
      userSettings[key as keyof IUserSettings] :
      defaultSettings[key as keyof IDefSettings];
  });

  return c;
}
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Ну так в пустом объекте нет кучи обязательных полей из интерфейсов. Как исправить? Добавить эти поля. Или пояснить зачем ты хочешь именно пустой объект считать экземпляром интерфейса IViewSettings и что ты собираешься потом делать с ошибками

Comment: "Добавить эти поля". Какие? Объект на выходе может быть двух типов в зависимости от входного типа defaultSettings. Какие поля туда добавлять, если в этих типах они разные? "Или пояснить зачем ты хочешь именно пустой объект считать экземпляром интерфейса IViewSettings". Не обязательно его считать экземпляром интерфейса, можно заменить на `const c = {};` но тогда на `c[key]` появляется другая ошибка и на `return c;`

Comment: Ну для начала совершенно непонятно какой смысл в этой функции с такой сигнатурой.

Comment: если у тебя есть `type IDefSettings = IViewSettings | IModelSettings` - почему ты используешь то его. то обычный union `IViewSettings | IModelSettings1`?

Comment: Можно и IDefSettings везде вместо IViewSettings | IModelSettings проставить. Ошибку это не исправляет, только будет `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IDefSettings'.ts(2322)`

Comment: "какой смысл в этой функции с такой сигнатурой". Разделить объект IUserSettings на IViewSettings и IModelSettings, которые будут использоваться в разных классах

Comment: Причина была указана выше: в твоих типах присутствуют **обязательные** поля. Чтобы можно было присвоить пустой объект - поля должны быть необязательными

Comment: Тогда появится много ошибок типа `Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.` или `Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`

Comment: @SOLID, тогда - это когда?

Comment: Если сделать эти поля необязательными в IViewSettings и IModelSettings. То везде в коде где используются эти значения, появятся такие ошибки. И ним добавится еще для `c[key]` в коде выше `Type 'string | number | boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | undefined'.
  Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'string | number | undefined'`

Comment: если тебе нужны значения по умолчанию - заполни их, например так: `const c: IDefSettings = Object.assign({}, defaultSettings);`

Comment: Да, точно. Еслинт только ругается на такое. Вот так работает `const c: IDefSettings = { ...defaultSettings };` а чтобы на c[key] не было ошибки нужно в интерфесах IViewSettings и IModelSettings исправить на `[index: string]: string | boolean | number | undefined;` не понятно только почему в обоих, в IModelSettings же не boolean

Comment: @Grundy, поправил код в вопросе, можете добавить его себе в ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: не надо исправлять ошибку в вопросе. Лучше сразу писать ответ с причиной ошибки и как поправить.